# How to know which column returned when I use RFE of skLearn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm trying to do something with feature engineer. So, I try to use the method RFE of Sklearn to do with it. But after I got the dataset who returned by RFE, I have no idea, which features is choosed, and which featured are deleted. So, is there any solution can make me know that?

```
v = trainDF.loc[:,['A','B','C','D']].as_matrix()
t = trainDF.loc[:,['y']].values.ravel()
RFE(estimator=LogisticRegression(), n_features_to_select=3).fit_transform(v,t)
```

=>

```
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RFE fitted object:

```
estimator = RFE(estimator=LogisticRegression(), n_features_to_select=3)
v_transform = estimator.fit_transform(v,t)
print(estimator.support_)  # The mask of selected features.
print(estimator.ranking_)  # The feature ranking
```